# Is there an equivalent to the JavaScript window object in IOS app environment?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, iphone, window

In a browser JavaScript environment there is a window object that holds properties that make up the application's global scope.

Is there a window object equivalent in an IOS app environment?

IOS has `windowScene: UIWindowScene` available.

In what way is it comparable?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it might help if you provide example JS code that you would like to execute.

Comment: If you are writing a native iOS app in Swift, then the last thing you want to do is think about anything in terms of how you do stuff in JavaScript. It would be much better to write your question showing what you have in Swift and clearly explain what it is you are having an issue with or what you are trying to do in the iOS app.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm really just trying to just see if there is that same type of abstraction in an IOS environment.

Comment: There is a global scope, but it isn't linked to any specific object. It is just the global scope.  I.e. if you declare a variable outside any scope then it is in the global scope

Comment: @Paulw11
So when an IOS app is running on a phone, the idea of having variables and functions organize under a single global object does not exists?

Comment: Would you not consider  `windowScene: UIWindowScene` to be similar?

Comment: People often use the application delegate object as it is a convenient Singleton, but generally creating your own model object is preferred

Comment: I am facing a same issue, I wanted to use `window.btoa()` in js which is in return used in swift but I am not always getting undefined